# jquery if not loaded not working

Tags: jquery

i'm using this below code for if jquery not loaded alert message, but else not working,

jQuery:

```
if (jQuery) {  

   alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

} else {

   alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
```

OR:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

    alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
```

Comment: "not working" Which means? Any error or what?

Comment: @roasted "not working" means "not working". means not work else block. ok?

Comment: Should work or shouldn't, i don't know

Answer (score 2):

Use this test to avoid an error :

```
if (window.jQuery) {
```

If the variable isn't defined, it's an error to test it. What you want to test is whether that the property `jQuery` of the global object is set.

Comment: i write else for your code but not working after disable browser javascript. `<script>
    if ( ! window.jQuery) alert('loded');
    else alert('not loaded');
</script>`

Comment: Of course it doesn't work after you disable JavaScript, this code is in JavaScript.

Comment: my problem is else block and i need to this if javascript not loaded alert error otherwise redirect to main page.